# What does it mean for a trait to have a lifetime parameter?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I understand how lifetime parameters apply to functions and structs, but what does it mean for a **trait** to have a lifetime parameter?  Is it a shortcut to introduce a lifetime parameter to its methods, or is it something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a trait with a lifetime bound, then *implementors* of the trait can participate in the same lifetime. Concretely, this allows you to store references with that lifetime. It is **not** a shortcut for specifying lifetimes on member methods, and difficulty and confusing error messages lie that way!

```rust
trait Keeper<'a> {
    fn save(&mut self, v: &'a u8);
    fn restore(&self) -> &'a u8;
}

struct SimpleKeeper<'a> {
    val: &'a u8,
}

impl<'a> Keeper<'a> for SimpleKeeper<'a> {
    fn save(&mut self, v: &'a u8) {
        self.val = v
    }
    fn restore(&self) -> &'a u8 {
        self.val
    }
}
```

Note how both the struct and the trait are parameterized on a lifetime, and that lifetime **is the same**.

> What would the non-trait versions of `save()` and `restore()` look like for `SimpleKeeper<'a>`?

Very similar, actually. The important part is that the struct stores the reference itself, so it needs to have a lifetime parameter for the values inside.

```rust
struct SimpleKeeper<'a> {
    val: &'a u8,
}

impl<'a> SimpleKeeper<'a> {
    fn save(&mut self, v: &'a u8) {
        self.val = v
    }
    fn restore(&self) -> &'a u8 {
        self.val
    }
}
```

> And would they mean exactly the same thing as the the trait version?

Yep!

Comment: Still a little fuzzy.  What would the non-trait versions of save() and restore() look like for SimpleKeeper<'a>?  And would they mean exactly the same thing as the the trait version?

Comment: Would this be it?    fn save<'a>(keep:&mut SimpleKeeper<'a>, v: &'a u8) { keep.val = v }
    fn restore<'a>(keep:& SimpleKeeper<'a>) -> &'a u8 { keep.val }

Comment: @goertzenator I attempted to answer. The important part is that the struct is also parameterized with the lifetime.

Comment: `how both the struct and the trait are parameterized on a lifetime`, is it force to do this?